# Restore bookmarks of deleted Chrome user?

Tags: google-chrome

accidently i deleted my chrome user on Windows 7. I tried to restore it, copied C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1

Everything looks fine expect all of my bookmarks are missing. I've checked and nothing find Bookmarks nor Bookmarks.bak
Have i got any chance to get back my bookmarks?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click to "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" folder and "Restore previous versions" fixed the problem - found the correct version of the file.

Comment: I know you got in trouble for posting this on the wrong community, but you just saved me DAYS of work. Thanks so much for answering! I ended up having to restore my entire `User Data` directory, but I've got all my stuff back.